# Why my Android emulator does not loading?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I try to load x86_64 android emulator (22 sdk version).

But during 3 hours it is not load.
My hardware is good (i5-3470,16 RAM,Win10 Pro).

I enable virtualization, disable Hyper-V, install Intel HAMX.

Android emulator settings:

```
Name: Xiaomi_MiPad2_API_22
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)
Path: C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Xiaomi_MiPad2_API_22.avd
Target: Google APIs (API level 22)
Skin: nexus_7_2013
SD Card: C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Xiaomi_MiPad2_API_22.avd\sdcard.img
Snapshot: yes
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Xiaomi MiPad2 2
vm.heapSize: 1024
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: User
hw.gps: no
hw.audioInput: yes
tag.id: google_apis
hw.camera.back: none
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Xiaomi_MiPad2_API_22
hw.camera.front: none
hw.lcd.density: 280
runtime.scalefactor: auto
avd.ini.displayname: Xiaomi MiPad2 API 22
snapshot.present: yes
hw.device.hash2: MD5:a6b74d11e6a69965f8fdbd7f3f89811c
hw.ramSize: 1536
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 500M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: no
```

Why it loading so long?

P.S. logs

```
 emulator: device fd:780
 HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
 emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
 emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
 emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

Comment: And it still loading during few hours...

Comment: Have you ever loaded it successfully?

Comment: Turn off  screenshots and than try

Comment: Once time it load successfull, but i uninstall Android Studio and clear my C drive. Then, i reinstall Studio into other drive.

Answer (score 0):

I thing problam first line of log enable windowes 10 mic permission will fix 
And second try edit launch emulator in low resolution 
Try wipe data first than start
If you stuck in black screen try cold boot
Let me know works